# Conveying 'cut-off time'

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, mathématiques, science

I am writing a script containing the following instructions:

> #Initialisation des paramètres
>
> g = 9.8066 # Accélération de la pesanteur [m / sˆ2]
>
> hauteur_initiale = 2.0 # y0 = hauteur de laquelle le ballon est lancé [m]
>
> increment_vitesse = 5.0 # Incrément de vitesse pour chaque itération [m / s]
>
> cutoff_time = 10.0 # Arrêt du calcul une fois que le temps d'impact dépasse le seuil.

For the sake of convenience here is the English version of the snippet.

```
   #Initialize parameters.

    g = 9.8066 # Gravitational acceleration [m/sˆ2]

    initial_height = 2.0 # y0 = height ball is thrown from [m]

    speed_increment = 5.0 # Speed increment for each iteration [m/s]

    cutoff_time = 10.0 # Stop computing after impact time exceeds cutoff.
```

I am puzzled how to call the variable `cutoff_time` in French. `temps_limite`, `seuil`, something else?

Comment: More context could be helpful but this somewhat reminds me compressors in audio processing in which a similar parameter is called 'Release'. Would 'relachement' work here? (accent intentionally not included since I don't know if the language you use supports them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On est à la limite entre une question de français et une question de développement informatique. Pour l'aspect informatique, je préfère toujours les noms explicites quand cela a son importance. Ici il semble que même en anglais le commentaire expliquant la variable n'est pas inutile, donc le nom pourrait sans doute être déjà en anglais plus explicite ou moins générique ("cutoff" est assez générique et la signification peut varier en fonction du contexte)

> limit_impact_time, impact_time_max, impact_time_threshold, ...

donc en français quelques propositions:

> limite_temps_impact, temps_impact_max, seuil_temps_impact,...

Petite remarque annexe: est-il vraiment nécessaire de traduire des noms de variables ?

Answer (score 2):

Pour ce que ça vaut, j'aurais appelé cette variable *t_max* ou *t_max_sim* si j'avais écrit ce code.

Le seul contexte où j'ai vu des variables appelées "cutoff" était en rapport avec des fréquences de filtres.  *cutoff frequency* est utilisé pour désigner la fréquence de coupure d'un filtre, nommer une variable de cette façon aurait amené une ambiguïté.